# Is elasticsearch, lostash and Kibana is freely available to create my own product which i sell?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

As I am new to ELK (Elastic-search, logstash, Kibana). Please let me know if can use these technologies free of cost for my own product?

Comment: ELK is open source project. You can setup configure for your project. If you are deploying or setup the ELK on any cloud service then cloud services may charges you for that.

Comment: Thank Ashish but is there any link which i can read to get know more about it

Comment: See this link https://www.edureka.co/blog/elk-stack-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Read the [license](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/master/licenses/ELASTIC-LICENSE.txt), or pay a lawyer to interpret it for you. Pay special attention to section 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the code is Apache 2 licensed, so you can do whatever you want from a commercial perspective. There are also the binaries for that, which always include `-oss` in the name.

Some parts are however under a difference license — that code is only in the `x-pack` folder of each project (eg https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/x-pack). If the [license](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/licenses/ELASTIC-LICENSE.txt) is unclear, there is an email address in that file where you can ask further questions.